# strings / substrings matching in tcsh

Tags: string, comparison, substring, tcsh

I'm struggling trying to use a concise comparison statement to avoid a bunch of "if a = b or a = c or a = d or a = e", etc.

Instead, I'm trying to use regex and pattern matching like you would do in perl.

with

> set st = "red"

the line

> if ($st =~ yellow|blue|red|green)

just doesn't work (if: Expression Syntax.)
I tried with quotes, parenthesis, but I never get the expected result, if no error.

is there a way to avoid the heavy construct:

if ($st == yellow) || ($st == blue) || ($st == red) || ($st == green) ?

Or another way to ask the same question: does tcsh allow for something like "if string a contains string b"? I couldn't find any notion of substring in tcsh reference.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Obligatory link: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know tsch, but looking at the info this page (under Special Characters): <s>http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Filename_substitution.html</s> 
http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/csh.html
it appears that you need to surround your colours with braces:

```
if ($st =~ {yellow,blue,red,green})
```

Comment: Wow, this works indeed! I had tried the curly brackets, but what I was missing was the "," delimiter between values :-/  Kept trying with the pipe character.

Much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The thing on the right hand side of the `~=` operator is a "glob-pattern", *not* a regular expression.  (For example, in a regexp `.` matches any character, and `.*` matches zero or more arbitrary characters; the glob-pattern equivalents are `?` and `*`.)

`{...,...,...}` is part of the syntax of glob-patterns.  `man tcsh` for a full description.

If you need to match regular expression, you can use the `expr` command; `man expr` or `info expr` for details.